# How does EOS prevent one contract from accessing another contract's tables without authorization?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, security

I noticed that multi-index (which is under eosio namespace) uses the following to prevent access to another contract's tables:

`eosio_assert( _code == current_receiver(), "cannot create objects in table of another contract" );`

But current_receiver is a global method defined in action.hpp.

So I wonder (because I don't have access to MacBook or Linux) would it be possible to create a smart contract that defines a function current_receiver() under eosio namespace and circumvent this security check to access another contract's tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the apply_context.cpp, there's three main db operations: db_store_i64, db_update_i64, db_remove_i64, you can't update other tables even if you changed the multi_index definition.

Comment: There are checks to see the the action receiver is the same as the table code in update and remove but there are no checks in store. I was able to successfully store under another contract using my hack contract. This means that I could potentially harm other users by writing under their code.

Comment: No, in the db_store_i64, only the receiver create the table, the receiver is not depend on you